# Передача функции родительскому sf компоненту React, по правилам Airbnb

Tags: reactjs, linter

Мне нужно передать функцию-обработчик событий из родительского функционального компонента в дочерний. Я реализовал это дело объявив функцию в родительском компоненте, а затем передав её в пропсы как handler={handlerName}. И это работает, у меня нету претензий, а у линтера настроенному по Airbnb есть, и аргументирует он свою позицию уверенно ([react/jsx-no-bind](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md)). Предлагает вместо handler={handlerName} использовать handler={this.handlerName}, но при попытке так сделать, снова ругается, что компонент функциональный, значит this использовать не должен ([react/no-this-in-sfc](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-this-in-sfc.md)). На данный момент я просто прописал игнор правила в файле, но стало очень интересно, можно ли как-то выйти из этой ситуации не используя классовые компоненты и не игнорируя правило?